# HQL syntax error - unexpected token in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Why does this HQL throw me the unexpected token? I've searched elsewhere for answers, but I can't really see where's the error in my syntax (it's probably a hql syntax error).

```
String hql = "from employee";
        
        if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()){ //NAME
            hql = "from employee where employee.name = "+nameField.getText();
            if(jCheckBox2.isSelected()){
                int value = (Integer)ageSpinner.getValue();//AGE
                hql = "from employee where employee.name = "+nameField.getText() + " and where employee.age = "+value;
                if(jCheckBox3.isSelected()){//ADDRESS
                    hql = "from employee where employee.name = "+nameField.getText() + " and where employee.age = "+value+" and where employee.address = " + addressField.getText();
                    if(jCheckBox4.isSelected()){//SALARY
                        hql = "from employee where employee.name = "+nameField.getText() + " and where employee.age = "+value+" and where employee.address = " + addressField.getText()+" and where employee.salary = " + jSlider1.getValue();
                    }
                }
                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think from is getting added twice...try and print the query...you would understand where to correct and what to correct

Answer (score 0):

If someone was wondering what the actual error was: it was the punctuation.
I've written `where employee.name = value` instead of `where employee.name = 'value'`